# Ubuntu 16.04: The required plugin could not be found

Tags: video, plugins

I'm trying to play a .mp4 video, however ubuntu can not find the plugins, I already installed the **ubuntu-restricted-extras** package but I did not succeed.

follows the message when trying to play a video:

Videos requires the installation of plug-ins to play media files of the following type: text / html decoder

***it is worth mentioning that this error happens only with some videos .mp4***

Comment: I would suggest to try out VLC. it's versatile, capable of playing almost all type of videos. it's available in the snap too. `snap install vlc`